# creating tree in recursive function

Tags: java, python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to implement C4.5 algorithm in java. To get initial idea about C4.5 algorithm I took a python code as reference from this [link](https://github.com/geerk/C45algorithm). On this project there is file named mine.py which contains the following function.

```
def mine_c45(table, result):
    """ An entry point for C45 algorithm.
        _table_ - a dict representing data table in the following format:
        {
            '<column name>': [<column values>],
            '<column name>': [<column values>],
            ...
        }
        _result_: a string representing a name of column indicating a result.
    """
    col = max([(k, gain(table, k, result)) for k in table.keys() if k != result],
              key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    tree = []
    for subt in get_subtables(table, col):
        v = subt[col][0]
        if is_mono(subt[result]):
            tree.append(['%s=%s' % (col, v),
                         '%s=%s' % (result, subt[result][0])])
        else:
            del subt[col]
            tree.append(['%s=%s' % (col, v)] + mine_c45(subt, result))
    return tree
```

By using the code in link I tried to convert this code in Java with some modification in it. I got succeeded getting the output which I want but the issue is I am not able to build a tree in recursive manner.

Here the code converted in java.

```
public void mineC45(Map<String, Attribute> table, String result) {
    int maxGain = 0;
    double[] gains = new double[table.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    SplitPoints point = null;
    for (Entry<String, Attribute> entry : table.entrySet()) {
        if (!entry.getKey().equals(result)) {
            boolean nominal = entry.getValue().isNominal();
            if (nominal)
                gains[counter++] = Utils
                        .gain(table, entry.getKey(), result);
            else {
                point = Utils.numericGain(table, entry.getKey(), result);
                gains[counter++] = point.getGain();
            }
        }
    }

    // calculate maximum gain column index
    maxGain = Utils.getMax(gains);
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(table.keySet());
    String column = keys.get(maxGain);
    if (table.get(column).isNominal()) {
        for (Map<String, Attribute> subTable : Utils.createSubTables(table,
                column)) {
            String value = subTable.get(column).getValues().get(0);
            if (Utils.isMono(subTable.get(result))) {
                System.out.println("\t" + column + " = " + value + " "
                        + result + " = "
                        + subTable.get(result).getValues().get(0));
            } else {
                subTable.remove(column);
                System.out.println(column + " = " + value + " ");
                mineC45(subTable, result);
            }
        }
    } else {
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map<String, Attribute> subTable : Utils.createNSubtables(
                table, column, result, point.getSplitValue())) {
            String sign = "";
            sign = first ? "<=" : ">";
            first = false;
            if (Utils.isMono(subTable.get(result))) {
                System.out.println("\t" + column + " "
                        + point.getSplitValue().toString() + " " + result
                        + " = " + subTable.get(result).getValues().get(0));
            } else {
                subTable.remove(column);
                System.out.println(column + " "
                        + point.getSplitValue().toString() + " ");
                mineC45(subTable, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I created `Map<String, Attribute>` which represents a table. The string key represents column name and attribute stores the list of values. If any one can explain me how would I convert the output into tree so that I can form rules.

Comment: What is the structure of the Python tree?  Did you print it out and examine it?  That doesn't appear in your posting.  What are the corresponding data structures in Java?  How does one usually implement a tree (of whatever type you desire) in Java?

Comment: The structure in python is very simple to understand by looking at code. The developer just appended nested array in it. It is possible in python but not in java so I want to add each node to tree just like JTree having DefaultMutableTreeNode I can create them, that is not an issue but my concern is I want it to be in correct way for e.g. check this picture you will come to know. http://tinyurl.com/juxudeb

Comment: I know it's a simple structure; I'm trying to help you refine your question so that someone can answer it quickly (I haven't coded Java for about 3 years).  Please edit these clarifications into the main body of the question.  Also, please describe more carefully where you are stuck.  You seem to know the names of the structures you want to use, and somewhat how they fit together.  As long as it sounds like you're asking us to design or write code for you, many people will ignore the question -- StackOverflow doesn't do most of that.